# Passing a fixed query term to django-haystack

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I'm looking to make a page that displays a fixed set of search results using django-haystack. I already have a page that can be used to make searches using haystack's `SearchView`, and want to make a second page that by default shows the results from a specific search -- in this example, searching for all documents that contain `Fruit`.

Here's my urls.py:

```
from haystack.views import SearchView
from django.conf.urls import url
import haystack

from .search_Queries import custom_query
from .forms import CustomSearchForm


urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^fruit/', SearchView(form_class=CustomSearchForm, 
            searchqueryset=custom_query)),
     url(r'^$', SearchView(form_class=haystack.forms.SearchForm,
                                         searchqueryset=custom_query),
     ]
```

And I am trying to make the view display the initial `Fruit` search term by overriding the `get_queryset` method in the form -- however, this doesn't seem to be the correct way to go about it

forms.py

```
class CustomSearchForm(SearchForm):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(CustomSearchForm, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.auto_query('Fruit')
        return queryset
```

How can I display a set of search results for a specific term as the default in a view using django-haystack? I want to make a separate view so that  my `^fruit/` URL shows the `Fruit` search results directly, rather than redirecting to `/q=Fruit`.

Answer (score 0):

what about a normal Django view with `SearchQuerySet` functionality inside:

```
url(r'^myquery/$', views.custom_query),
```

and inside `views.py`:

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from django.http JsonResponse

def custom_query(request):
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().auto_query('fruit').load_all()
    # and do whatever you want with the sqs
    return JsonResponse({'result': sqs[0].object.pk})
```